# What is the role of an if following a function argument

Tags: python

```
def valid_month(month):
    if month:
        cap_month = month.capitalize()
        if cap_month in months:
            return cap_month
```

What is the role of that `if` on the second line? Does it checks if there is an argument?

Answer (score 4):

In python, an empty string, or an empty list or set, etc are all `False` in boolean context, also `None` is `False` in boolean context (also number 0 is False) (that is when used in if statement), the check `if month:` , checks whether month is not `None` or `month` is not empty string (I am guessing month is string, as you call `capitalize()` on it).

Only if month is not empty and month is not None, the statements inside `if` are executed.

Examples to show this behavior -

```
>>> s = ''
>>> if not s:
...     print("Blah")
...
Blah
>>> s = 'abcd'
>>> if s:
...     print("Blah1")
...
Blah1
>>> s = ''
>>> if s:
...     print("Will not print")
...
>>> s = None
>>> if s:
...     print("Will not print")
```

Reference for Python [Truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html) .

Answer (score 3):

The line `if month:` is a [Truth Value Test](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

This means it checks that the variable `month` **is not** one of these values:

> - `None`
> - `False`
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, `0`, `0.0`, `0j` (and `0L` if Python 2.7).
> - any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.
> - any empty mapping, for example, `{}`.
> - instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__nonzero__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or `bool` value `False`.

Comment: Good idea to list all cases where if would evaluate to False.

Answer (score 1):

As per your sample program:

```
def valid_month(month):
    if month:
        cap_month = month.capitalize()
        if cap_month in months:
            return cap_month
```

**if month is list:**

1. A list of months are passed to the function `valid_month`
2. The first `if` checks if the month is not a empty list then you have used a function `capitalize()` on the list and getting a value
3. In second `if` you are checking if the value is present in the list and returning it

**If month is a string:**

1. A string month is  passed to the function `valid_month`
2. The first `if` checks if the month is not a empty string then you have used a function `capitalize()` on the string to capitalize the month
3. In second `if` you are checking if the capitalized month  is present in the input month and returning it

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement is to validate the parameter (i.e., check if it is null).

Comment: Check if it is None is more appropriate.